How can I unsubscribe user from APNs push notifications from pinpoint upon sign-out with Amplify for react-native v6?
How can I unsubscribe user from APNs push notifications from pinpoint upon sign-out with Amplify JS for react-native v6?
I'm using AWS Pinpoint SendUserMessages API.
And according to docs
"If the value of EndpointStatus for an endpoint is INACTIVE, and you send a message to that endpoint through a campaign or journey, Amazon Pinpoint doesn’t attempt to send the message. If you send a message using the SendMessages and SendUserMessages API, the value of EndpointStatus is ignored."
Tried suggestion from here, by setting userId: '' with identifyUser from 'aws-amplify/push-notifications', but it did not work.
I expected not to receive APNs push notification from Pinpoint after user sign out, however still getting them.
